# Is it on-topic to ask about a non-alcoholic substitute for liquor?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, specific-question

Would a question about [finding a non-alcoholic substitute](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/86292/17272) to *mimic the flavor* of a particular liquor be topical for Beer, Wine & Spirits?

(Note that I'm not requesting migration, or saying it's necessarily off-topic at Seasoned Advice — but I honestly wasn't sure whether this would be something on-topic here or not!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that its fine as it is still about finding some thing alcohol related even if it is alcohol free and as we are still in a beta for this stack I think it is worth experimenting with different types of questions (as long as they are related), I would see no issues with a question of this kind